# Class A have 3 method , class B have 2 method ,classB inherited class A , how do you call method of class A by creating object of classB?

Tags: inheritance

Class A have 3 method , class B have 2 method , classB inherited classA , how do you call method of class A by creating object of class B

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.
Also, if this is your homework, please read [homework](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) first

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call methods of class A by creating object of class B

```
class A{  
 void m1() {
     System.out.println("M1"); 
 } 
 
 void m2() {
     System.out.println("M2"); 
 } 
 
 void m3() {
     System.out.println("M3"); 
 } 
}  
public class B extends A{  
    
 void m4() {
     System.out.println("M4"); 
 } 
 
 void m5() {
     System.out.println("M5"); 
 } 
  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
   B b = new B();  
   
   b.m1();
   b.m2();
   b.m3();
   b.m4();
   b.m5();
     
}  
}
```